# Use DNN Profile/User objects from ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, profile, dotnetnuke

Is there any way to leverage the DNN components for creating users and setting their profile properties from within a standard ASP.NET application?  I am able to access this base ASP.NET Membership database without issue, but without being able to use DNN.Entities.Users.* I cannot truly create users and set/get their profile properties.

Comment: Ooh, I'm going to watch this one with interest. I've been intending to do something very similar, myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done it, but I am sure it can be done, and it's probably not that hard.  Essentially you want a membership provider that runs outside of DNN.  You might even get away with simply calling methods on the existing membership provider.  I would start by reviewing the source of the ASPNetMembership provider.

http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

The provider is at \Library\Providers\MembershipProviders\AspNetMembershipProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you could setup your web.config with the appropriate connection strings and include the DotNetNuke dll in your bin directory and have a shot ;)  Might need to include some other dependent DLL's and work through a couple error messages.

But in theory I think you could eventually get there going with this route.